# Connecting two virtual machine on two different hosts on the same LAN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-adapter

How to? I've tried to connect them through "bridged network" in virtual box (i'm using debian8 on both machine), but i can't ping a machine from the other. Address are static on both `10.0.2.30` and `10.0.2.20`. How can i resolve this? In case it matter, both my host is Windows10 and are connected through wifi. Thanks!

Comment: How did you pick the static IPs? Are the host machines really on the same `10.0.20.0/24` subnet? Can you ping the other host from your guest?

Comment: Can you ping the virtual machines from both Windows10 hosts?

Comment: I've tried from cmd on windows host and i have host unreachable if i `ping 10.0.2.30`

Comment: Do your windows hosts have addresses in the same subnet (probably 10.0.20.x)? (command `ipconfig` in a windows cmd window)

Comment: windows host got 192.168.56.1, how to make it work?

Comment: So your guests are not in the same network as the host system(s). Try assigning them free addresses in the range 192.168.56.xx (if your netmask is 255.255.255.0).